# eregi_replace Deprecated error

Tags: php

I have run several searches here as well as on Google, but can't quite figure out what the proper syntax is to fix the following three lines to use preg_replace instead of eregi_replace.  Help?

```
$regexp_search = 'width=".{3}"';
$regexp_replace = 'width="'.$autotube_size.'"';
$autostart = eregi_replace($regexp_search, $regexp_replace, $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

For that simple pattern just add delimiters and i modifier:

```
$regexp_search = '/width=".{3}"/i';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex wizard... http://www.monstaregex.com

Also has a good tutorial if you're unfamiliar with regex.